# Play Framework Json validation that needs to check database

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to check if posted field for existing entity is unique. I'd like to use validator. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
  val slugUnique: Reads[String] =
    Reads.StringReads.filter(ValidationError("not_unique"))(str =>
      Entity.find(str).isEmpty
    )
```

but I need to pass id of the current entity to this method to check only other records and not the current. Is this possible? Or it should be done in some other way?

Comment: Why don't you make it `def` and pass an id?

Comment: Great idea. How can I use this def from controller action then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the slugUniqe a function using `def` then it can have a parameter. so

```
def slugUnique(id: Long): Reads[String] =
    Reads.StringReads.filter(ValidationError("not_unique"))(str =>
      Entity.find(str).isEmpty
    )
```

then to call it from the controller you need to explicitly pass the reads function, something like this

`request.body.validate[String](slugUnique(id))`